# Bat script for SFTP upload of specific extensions only

Tags: batch-file, automation, sftp, batch-processing

Say I have a folder containing jpg files, mp4 files and some other extensions.

I would like to write a bat script that uploads to SFTP the jpg and mp4 files only and ignores the others.

The bat file is also located inside this folder along with the jpg's and mp4's.

Suppose these are the sftp credentials:
Username:root.
Password: password.
Hostname: sftp://12.345.67.890.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any command-line SFTP client can do that.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/):

```
winscp.com /command "open sftp://root:password@12.345.67.890" "put *.jpg *.mp4 /target/path/" "exit"
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

You can also use [psftp](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html).

(From the reference to a .bat file, I assume you are on Windows)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*